# Handlebars math expressions when looping through array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm practicing node, and I ran to a little problem. I'm using handlebars as a templating engine, and mongoose for interaction with my database. In my .hbs template I am looping through each record from the database, and of course I passed the records to my view with

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
Exam.find(function(err, predmeti) {
if (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
  res.render('index',{
    predmeti: predmeti
  })
})

});
```

Now when im looping through `predmeti` with #each, engine throws an error when I try doing math expressions such as

```
{{#each predmeti}}
 <h1>{{100/(brKolokvijuma/finished)}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

`brKolokvijuma and finished` both have a number value, but for some reason I get a error *Expecting ID got OPEN_SEXPR*

So I'm assuming handlebars won't let me do math expressions when I'm looping through an array. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are plugins for Handlebars to enable you to do the things they think you shouldn't do in views, but everyone still wants to.

For example [the Assemble.io maths helpers](http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-math.html) and nested expressions would enable you to do something like:

```
{{#each predmeti}}
   <h1>{{divide 100 (divide brKolokvijuma finished)}}</h1>
{{/each}}
```

A second method, if your maths expressions are not so varied and reused around your views (common calculations e.g. tax or rounding), you could write your own simpler/lighter plugin:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("divideMyThings", function(thing1, thing2, thing3) {
  return thing1 / thing2 / thing3;
});
```

Called in your template:

```
{{divideMyThings 100 brKolokvijuma finished}}
```

Thirdly you can often precompute data-tables until you only have one variable, and then use the [builtin lookup feature](http://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup). This requires no additional plugins. This is probably not helpful to this specific question, but I thought I'd mention it as a tool.